# How to automatically generate a table?

Tags: tables, cross-referencing

Here is the stupid way of doing things:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{exercise}
\setcounter{exercise}{0}
\newcommand{\exercise}[1]{
\stepcounter{exercise}
\bigbreak\textbf{Exercise \arabic{exercise} (#1pt)}\par
}

\begin{document}

% To be automatically generated
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Ex} & \textbf{Pt} \\ 
\hline
1 & 3 \\
\hline
2 & 5 \\
\hline
3 & 2 \\
\hline
\textbf{Total} & \textbf{10} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}


\exercise{3}
First exercise

\exercise{5}
Second exercise

\exercise{2}
Third exercise

\end{document}
```

How can I automatically generate the table from the exercises?

[image]

Many thanks for your help!

Olivier

Comment: The exam package!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `.aux` file:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{exercise}
\newcommand{\exercise}[1]{%
  \bigbreak
  \stepcounter{exercise}%
  \textbf{Exercise \arabic{exercise} (#1pt)}%
  \writepoints{#1}%
  \par\nopagebreak
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\writepoints}[1]{%
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\vogel@addpoints{\arabic{exercise}}{#1}}%
}
\newcounter{vogel@points}
\newcommand{\vogel@addpoints}[2]{%
  \g@addto@macro\vogel@pointtable{#1 & #2 \\ \hline}%
  \addtocounter{vogel@points}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\vogel@pointtable}{}%
\newcommand{\printpointtable}{%
  \begin{flushleft}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \hline
  \textbf{Ex} & \textbf{Pt} \\
  \hline
  \vogel@pointtable
  \textbf{Total} & \arabic{vogel@points} \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \end{flushleft}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\printpointtable

\exercise{3}
First exercise

\exercise{5}
Second exercise

\exercise{2}
Third exercise

\end{document}
```

The idea is that `\exercise` writes a note in the `.aux` file; the data is read in at begin document and used in `\printpointtable`.

Half points might be supported as well, if needed.

[image]

Comment: What does this macro do `\newcommand{\vogel@pointtable}{}`?

Comment: @AndréC That initializes the container for the table rows.

Comment: What do you mean, initialize?

Comment: @AndréC In order to execute `\g@addto@macro\vogel@pointtable{...}` we need a macro that already exists.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a macro that does nothing at all and to which you add arguments with `\g@addto@macro` on which I have done research to try to understand the logic of your code. But it still resists my understanding.  Why is it necessary to build a macro that does nothing at all and then add parameters to it? Couldn't we have given parameters to this macro as soon as it was built?

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

Comment: @AndréC Each `\vogel@addpoints` command adds tokens to the replacement text of `\vogel@pointtable`. This way, when the macro is used, the final result (that is, the table body) will be produced.

Comment: Okay, that's really smart.